# Subtract Two Negative Binary Numbers

Tags: computer-science, binary

Given the example (in decimal) `-32 - (-16)`, how would this be done in binary? Would you simply add their complements together or would you need to use their two's complement, or?...

I'd appreciate it if you could provide a visual, step-by-step, to help me wrap my head around it and try to help me understand the logic behind each step.

Comment: So you're asking how to compute $-100000-(-10000)$ in base 2?

Comment: Yea, I guess. I'm in a computer science class and this is one of the concepts they're trying to teach...

Comment: You should say you are expressing the numbers in 2s complement notation.  It would be more normal in math to use sign/magnitude, so $-3_{10}=-11_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For demonstration purpose, I am using $8$-bit $2$'s complement representation of the given numbers. We have $-32_{10} = \color{red}{1}1100000_2$ and $-16_{10} = \color{red}{1}1110000_2$. Here, the most-significant bit (shown in red) carries a weight of $-128$. Since $a-b = a+(-b)$, we add the $2$'s complement of $b$ to $a$. Now, $2$'s complement of $\color{red}{1}1110000_2$ is $\color{red}{0}0010000_2$. Therefore, $$-32_{10}-(-16_{10}) = \color{red}{1}1100000_2+\color{red}{0}0010000_2 = \color{red}{1}1110000_2 =-16_{10}.$$

Comment: I tried to follow along with a similar problem, $-64 - (-32)$ but am not getting the expected answer... Could you please add a second example or try to explain it with a more defined series of steps perhaps? Thanks! :)

Comment: @user1960364 Most likely, you had a difficulty in correctly representing these numbers. Check the updated answer where I increased the number of bits to 8 in the binary representation. Hopefully, this time you get the correct answer after following the mentioned procedure.